# Why Database.Log is not an event?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

**Entity Framework** recently added the ability to capture the SQL queries with the `Database.Log` hook.

What surprised me is that it is not implemented as a "protected encapsulation-friendly armored" **delegate**, a.k.a an **event**, but as a bare **multicast delegate**.

And indeed I've seen members of the EF team doing this:

```
context.Database.Log = sql => Debug.WriteLine(sql);
```

Where I'd expect:

```
context.Database.Log += sql => Debug.WriteLine(sql);
```

to avoid erasing previous registered handlers.

Moreover with a bare delegate we can call it directly:

```
context.Database.Log("SORRY SQL IS TOO MEDIEVAL FOR ME");
```

Which of course is not something I'd expect to do.

Is there some rationales behind this choice or the original developer missed a coffee break and forgot to add the `event` keyword before committing. ;)

EDIT : all of a sudden I have a really terrible doubt: as a .Net practitioner and trainer I've "measured" that 97% of .Net devs are convinced that events MUST be `EventHandler`s, so if I was auditing a "normal" company source code I would think: it's OK, the guy does not know it can use any delegate type and for simplicity (we only need to transfer a `string`) didn't want to use an `EventHandler` so he thought he couldn't use and event so instead used a bare delegate without considering encapsulation "issues".
But this would be for a "normal" company and I think it's highly improbable from a Microsoft developer...

Comment: From your "About Me" ... looks like you are a `Super Man` :)

Comment: And I only talk of my official activities, not my evil plan to rule the universe. ;)

Comment: In the end, we can only guess what their reasons were. To me this is "opinion-based".

Comment: Nope please, let me make it clear: I'm not asking for guesses but for FACTS. Either an insider which would say "sorry we should really not have let an intern do the job" ;) or a guru saying "let me teach you life: making it an event would have broken this and that, and would have made this and that more complex; moreover I once recall a similar design decision..." Well you get the idea, some FACTS that would explain it. :)

Comment: OK, maybe an insider will chime in. Until then I see a three-line answer giving rise to nine long comments. To me that's discussion and opinion. The question is interesting, sure (I mean it), but it's just that it's not on-topic at StackOverflow.

Comment: This long discussion was (is?) not specifically about `Log`. It relates to more advanced EF logging and tracing capabilities. I may directly mail Rowan Miller from the EF team...

Answer (score 1):

That is merely per-instance logging in case you quickly want to create output for one specific `DbContext` instance, and not to create generic logger for entire application.

If you want to log everything and set it on the application level, then you need to implement `IDbCommandInterceptor`:

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#BuildingBlocks)

You can have as many interceptors as you like and use `dbContext.Database.Log` as well at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link but my question is about "design", the "why", and unfortunately this page does not answer it. :)

Comment: What event are you actually trying to subscribe to? There is no "QueryGenerated" event, or "CommandExecuted" event or anything like that. This is just passing in the delegate that will be executed whenever some T-SQL has been sent to the database. So if you'd like i.e. to filter what you're logging, you can't this way => you need to use interceptor where you can customize what are you logging, aka what "event".

Comment: Invoking some treatments when something happens, like the emission of a new SQL request, can be considered an "event"; tough in this case this is more of a raw old school **callback**. Moreover the event in C#/VB.Net offers some nice features related to **encapsulation**: you can only register and unregister handlers/callbacks. So IMHO making `Log` an event in the C#/VB.Net term would make more sense, even if it wouldn't implement the  `EventHandler` contract.

Comment: If you take a look into ASP.NET MVC i.e., it has a concept of ActionFilters, where you define logic that you want to execute on several steps of pipeline (OnActionExecuting, OnActionExecuted, OnResultExecuting, OnResultExecuted). Then you register your filter globally and your logic is executed on every request. There are no event handlers here either, and it is similar approach to IDbCommandInterceptor. Would you consider ActionFilters bad pattern as well? I'm trying to tell you that .Log is not place where you'd hook up to listen onto events globally, IDbCommandInterceptor is.

Comment: PS: I like this discussion, keep it going until they tell us to move on chat :)

Comment: I have no concrete need for interception, my only "concern" is about the specific design of `Log`. :) As for action filters I guess you can't unregister one you haven't registered yourself. Because this is exactly what you can do with `Log`: unregister all the other people that are interested in SQL logs. This is of course more of a theoretical issue as an instance of `DbContext` is hardly ever shared, and on the contrary it is more often than not encapsulated/hidden inside a **repository** which will register once for `Log`.

Comment: From my perspective, .Log is just quickest way to troubleshoot something, without having to write proper implementation with IDbCommandInterceptor. IDbCommandInterceptor allows you to do what you're asking in a more pipeline-based way. So if .Log was the only way to do the logging, I'd 100% agree with you that it is not good implementation. However since it's instance specific, thus not shared as you've said yourself, it's just there for commodity, nothing else :)

Comment: Yeah I agree, as I said IRL it's not that important that `Log` is not an event. But it costs nothing to make it better: for the developer it's the `event` keyword to add, for the user it's a `+` sign. I'm myself a pragmatic dev (well, at least I try :)) and when "a little better" means "a lot more complex" then I prefer the quick-and-dirty way, but in this case I don't see any reason to avoid what seems to be the cleaner way.

Comment: Moreover it's the first time I've seen such an API in the .Net framework which uses events everywhere else I know, and respecting conventions is really important, it makes the code more easily discoverable for newcomers. It's why we stick with `EventHandler` for events though sometimes it makes the code uselessly heavier: the best illustration is `INotifyPropertyChanged` for which the community has created dozens of ways to make it easier to use because otherwise it's quite cumbersome to pass a `PropertyChangedEventArgs` instead of a simple string.